# Exemplo de Callbacks em c

Tags: c, callback

Gostaria de exemplo de uso de callback em c que permita registrar callbacks a serem chamadas quando um evento ocorrer.

Answer (score 1):

Em C as "callback" não são iguais as do javascript que são bem mais implmentadas, são simplesmente funções que são passadas em argumentos de outras funções usando `function pointers`.
Veja este exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void funcaoA() 
{ 
    printf("Olá"); 
} 

void funcaoB(void (*func)()) 
{ 
    (*func) ();
    printf(" Mundo \n");
} 

int main() 
{ 
    void (*func)() = &funcaoA; 

    funcaoB(*func); 

   return 0; 
}
```

Pode testar o código acima [aqui](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/C-callback).
Você encontra um material legal para ler sobre o assunto [aqui](https://opensourceforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/) e [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callbacks-in-c/).